# relative amenability of von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, amenability

Let $\cal{M}$ be a finite von Neumann algebra and $\cal{N}$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of $\cal{M}$.
The von Neumann  algebra $\cal{M}$ is is amenable relative to
 $\cal{N}$ if there exists a norm one projection of $<\cal{M},\cal{N}>$ onto
$\cal{M}$. See Nicolas Monod, Sorin Popa, On co-Amenability for groups and von
Neumann algebras. (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301348).

Question: Can we characterize  the relative amenability of  von Neumann  algebras   in terms of  ﬁrst Hochschild cohomology group?

Comment: Have you considered the case $\mathcal N = \mathbb C$?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07329 ?